# Installing older gdb version

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm having a problem with the latest `gdb` so I want to use an older one. I found the `gdb` archive [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) but how do I compile/install one of them so it can be used?

According to the [manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_27.html), first `configure`:

```
$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[...]
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Then `make`:

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/gdb-7.7'
Configuring in ./libiberty
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for makeinfo... /root/Desktop/gdb-7.7/missing makeinfo --split-size=5000000
[...]
```

But it results in an error:

```
remote-utils.c:436:19: error: ‘hexchars’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-const-variable=]
 static const char hexchars[] = "0123456789abcdef";
                   ^~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:238: recipe for target 'remote-utils.o' failed
make[4]: *** [remote-utils.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/gdb-7.7/gdb/gdbserver'
Makefile:1345: recipe for target 'subdir_do' failed
make[3]: *** [subdir_do] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/gdb-7.7/gdb'
Makefile:1018: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/gdb-7.7/gdb'
Makefile:8611: recipe for target 'all-gdb' failed
make[1]: *** [all-gdb] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/gdb-7.7'
Makefile:832: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The guide on downgrading programs found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/) also didn't help since I always got "version not found" errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdb="7.8.1"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '7.8.1' for 'gdb' was not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to compile an older GDB using newer GCC.

This generally doesn't work: newer GCC enables new warnings, and GDB developers fix these warnings (usually before the new GCC version is actually released).

You should be able to disable these warnings with:

```
 ./configure 'CFLAGS=-w'
```

or by editing the generated Makefile and modifying the `CFLAGS` there.

Other alternatives:

- you could actually fix the code to not produce the warning (deleting line 436 of `remote-utils.c` should do it), or
- you could install older GCC of the same "vintage", and build GDB with it (perhaps in a virtual machine).

Answer (score 2):

You can check error-related configure flags using this command:

`./configure --help | grep error`

there you should see:

`--enable-werror         enable -Werror in bootstrap stage2 and later`

So you can disable treating warnings as errors:

`./configure --disable-werror`